# forward specific domain to another DNS server with BIND's named

Tags: bind

I'm having some trouble configuring my DNS server.
It is working perfectly for a number of different local domains but when I can't configure it such that if it receives requests for a given domain it forwards them to another DNS server.

Here is what I have configured:

The domain is `vume`, for example: `server1.vume`. And the DNS servers that I want to redirect all the vume requests to are 192.168.5.5 and 192.168.5.6.

```
zone "vume" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 192.168.5.5; 192.168.5.6; };
};

zone "5.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 192.168.5.5; 192.168.5.6; };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by changing this in the named.conf

```
dnssec-enable no;
dnssec-validation no;
```

Comment: Can you explain _why_ this solved the issue? Please also mark your answer as the accepted solution.